# generate password reset token in node.js

Tags: node.js, forgot-password

How do I generate a password reset token in node.js that can be used in a url?

I just need the method for generating the token:

```
user.reset_password_token = ???;
user.reset_password_expire = expire_date;
```

Edit -- here's the solution:

```
user.reset_password_token = require('crypto').randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code? : )

Comment: i added the solution I went with.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I ended up using that, i did 48 bytes, I guess it doesnt really matter except for taking up more space, or you think 32 is enough?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm using this to generate my auth-token:

```
require('crypto').randomBytes(32, function(ex, buf) {
    var token = buf.toString('hex');
});
```

[Crypto Node.js v0.8.9 Manual & Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback)

Comment: How would I use that w/ the code above? Do I have to move everything into randomBytes callback now?

Comment: `user.reset_password_token = require('crypto').randomBytes(32).toString('hex');`

Comment: How big does the token need to be realisitically? Does it need to be 32 or can it be 8 for a shorter url.

Comment: @chovy A reset token is literally a password, so in general anything that is true for storing passwords is true for reset tokens. They aren't as large of a concern as passwords though because tokens should have additional restrictions, such as time limits and limited attempts. In my opinion, you'll be fine with 8 characters if your restrictions are strong enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
function customToken() {
    var buffreValue = new Buffer(64);
    for (var i = 0; i < buffreValue.length; i++) {
        buffreValue[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    }
    var token = buffreValue.toString('base64');
    return token;
}
var getToken = customToken()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, first, you should create an **instance method** on your **schema**, so,  your code must be something like this :

Before you write this function, you must add two fields in your schema.

**1. passwordResetExpire**
**2. passwordResetToken**

**and the function is:**

```
userSchema.methods.createPasswordResetToken = function () {
      const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
      this.passwordResetToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(resetToken).digest('hex');
      // Please note that you need to specify a time to expire this token. In this example is (10 min)
      this.passwordResetExpire = Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000;
      return resetToken;
    };
```