# Store data from a http request from a manually typed url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

After recently picking up web development, I've become unstuck with this issue. I am trying to implement a user password reset functionality. The user receives an email with a url appended with a random token, they then click the url, and are redirected to my site. Now, the user inputs their new password, and then their token is compared to the token stored in the sqlite database, and checked for expiry, and if all is well, the new password is dealt with.

So, my issue is how can I take the query details from the get request, and then respond to client side to acquire the new password and then send a new post request, which will then retrieve the previously stored token and continue.

My original idea was some sort of global variable, i.e.

```
app.get('/set', function(req, res) {
  // var token = req.query.token;
  // var email = req.query.email;
  var token = '1';
  var email = '11111@outlook.com';
  res.send(email);
});

app.get('/get', function(req,res) {
  console.log(res.app.get('reset-email'));
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

But obviously this is a terrible idea. I'm fairly sure there is a flaw in my fundamental understanding of httprequests, but this one has stumped me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To the first problem, I used this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578248/generate-password-reset-token-in-node-js) and it works perfectly. As for the fundamental understanding, I have used [this](https://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter14.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head: If you are using express sessions, you can set the value of the token on the session (`req.session.token=<access_token>`) and use it for subsequent requests (`var token=req.session.token`)...

Another alternative is: you can render the token down as a hidden field as a part of your password reset form. This will pass the token as a part of your POST request when the user submits the form with the new password.

Note:
Using `res.app.get` (and globals in general) is a bad idea as this value will be shared across requests. Since requests in express are handled asynchronously, it's quite possible (or even probable) that two parallel requests will cause a race condition.

EDIT: Sample Snippet to explain my comment in detail:

```
app.get('/reset',function(req, res){
    var token  = req.query.token;
    var html = `
    <html>
        <body>
            <form method="POST" action="/reset">
                <input type=text style="display:none;" name=token value="${token}"/>
                <input type=password name=new_password value="" />
                <input type=submit value=Submit />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    `;
    res.status(200);
    res.type('.html'); 
    res.send(html);
})

app.post('/reset', function(req, res){
    //req.body should have both the password and the token
    //(Assuming you have the body parser middleware available before this request handler)
})
```

Comment: I was considering sessions, but I assumed I was just missing something. For your alternative, it is not how I can pass the token from client to server side, it is how I can get the token from the url to the client side that is the issue.

Comment: My alternative actually suggests rendering down the token as a part of your form to submit the new password (ie, the client gets the token in the HTML body of the form as a hidden input). If the URL is not changed, you can even parse it of the URL on the client using `window.location.href` but that would be risky. Rendering your form down with the token set as a hidden input's value would be a better option.

Comment: I'm assuming that on clicking the link the email (which has the token as query parameter) your sever responds with a form. Since your server renders the form and also knows what the token is via query params, your can build your form to have a hidden input. `<input type=text style="display:none" value="<access_token>" />`. So when the user hits submit to change password, this value is bundled with the POST request so you can use it on the server to validate the request and act on it.

Comment: From the answer below, I think my issue has been that I haven't heard of `res.render`. So, was not aware that I can render into a user's client side, from server side, without a client side function which had constructed the httprequest, I'll have a go at this.

Comment: Yup. `res.render` uses template engines to do the job (usually `jade` or `pug` by default).. You can even build the html out as a string in javascript if templating is not used in your application and you only need it for this. Like `var html = '<html><body>.... <input ... value='+req.query.token+' />...</body></html>'.` and then do `res.send(html)`

Comment: I see, this was a method I tried, but I had all sorts of issues with assets not loading, it seems I may have to switch to using some sort of javascript templating, if as you suggest is the only way without it.

Answer (score 1):

Youve got only one global variable. Therefore if you get two requests, they will share the same variable and one resets the password of the other. So yes, thats a terrible idea. The probably easiest solution would be to just show a reset form on the first page and include the token into the form. That would look like:

```
 app.get("/reset-password", (req, res) => {
   res.render("reset.ejs", { token: req.query.token });
 });
```

Now the related form in `reset.ejs` might look like:

```
 <form action = "/reset-password" method = "POST">
   <input style="display:none" name = "token" value = "<%= token %>" />
   <input name = "password" />
   <button type="submit"> Reset </button>
 </form>
```

So now when the post request comes in, we get both the token and the password and can validate them:

```
 app.post("reset-password", (req, res) => {
   const {password, token} = req.body;
   //...
 });
```

Comment: I see, my missing knowledge was `res.render`, so was not aware that I could alter client side html from server side without the http response running through a client side function which constructed the request.

Comment: @ellis well the server decides what he sends to the client :)